# Make d3 bar chart responsive

Tags: d3.js

I'm using the following code to make my bar chart responsive:

```
d3.select( window ).on( 'resize', function( ) {
  var targetWidth = parseInt( d3.select( '#chart' ).style( 'width' ), 10);
  chart.attr( 'width', targetWidth );
  chart.attr( 'height', targetWidth / aspect );
});
```

This only works for part of the graph. How would I make the entire graph responsive? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can see all of the code here: http://codepen.io/jesouhaite08/pen/fhvzA

Comment: This [PEN](http://codepen.io/fernoftheandes/pen/qoJCp?editors=101) should get you going. I had and example laying around with jQuery so I used it, but you can do the same with plain javascript. You can also play with the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

Comment: Why don't use pourcent width / height ? Instead of just "targetWidth" for width, you can use : "targetWidth / totalWidth + '%'"

Answer (score 0):

There are two options in d3 to make the chart responsive.

- Using view box and aspect ratio
- Using resize function

using resize function :[Responsive Bar chart](https://github.com/caravinden/D3_Element_Creation)

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way of doing this in D3 You can make the chart resize using a combination of viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes on the SVG element.

```
const svg = d3
  .select('div#chart-container')
  .append('svg')
  .style(
    'padding',
    marginRatio.top +
      ' ' +
      marginRatio.right +
      ' ' +
      marginRatio.bottom +
      ' ' +
      marginRatio.left +
      ' '
  )
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
  .attr(
    'viewBox',
    '0 0 ' +
      (width + margin.left + margin.right) +
      ' ' +
      (height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  )
```

See here for reference: https://eddyerburgh.me/create-responsive-bar-chart-d3-js